# Fetch messages beyond the cache

Tags: node.js, api, discord, discord.js

I'm developing a BOT that replies to messages.
But there is a problem that due to 13v, BOT can only fetch messages which are in the `cache`.

> const refMessageID = await logChannel.messages.`cache`.find(c => c.content === referenceMessage.content)

As you can see here, I need to fetch the message from the cache.
Do you know any `option/method/technique` from where I can fetch the messages even if they are not in the cache?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this in an asynchronous function:

```js
const messages = await logChannel.messages.fetch();
const message = messages.find(c => c.content == referenceMessage.content);
```

`logChannel.messages.fetch()` will fetch **all** messages in the channel and returns the same object as `cache`, but not missing messages out.

Comment: it does not fetch **all** messages, it fetches 50 by default you can provide more by specifying `{limit: /**...*/}` as the first parameter to the function.